# function doesnt recognize .data() value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this  code, where if click on `.comments` depending on if having prior comments...it loads the comments + a comment form, or just a form (no comments) in `.LastComments`

**HTML**

```
<div class="comment" data-number_comments="7" data-user="Joe">
  [Click to comment]
</div>

<div class="LastComments"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.comment').on('click', function() {

  var user = $(this).data("user");
  var number_comments = $(this).data("number_comments");

  if (number_comments) {
    $(".LastComments").load(url, {
      vars
    }, /*Load_newform here*/ )

  } else {

  /*Load_newform here*/
  }

});
```

**FUNCTION**

```
function Load_newform() {
  form = "<form>Hi " + user + " post a comment </form>";
  $(".LastComments").append(form);
}
```

***PROBLEM***

The function gets values from the `.data` returned so It doesnt show the `user` value and others I'm working with. How do I retrieve the values to make it work correctly?

Comment: your function has no params? how does it know what user is?

Comment: Initially the function is within the click event...in this case It uses `.data(user)` value. Now I want to put this function outside of the click event and thisproblem shows up

Comment: Pass `user` as an argument to the `Load_newform()` function

Comment: `function doesnt recognize .data() value jquery` -> this title is wrong. The problem is with scoping.

Comment: what would it be a correct way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a variable is required in two different scopes, you can't retrieve it just by calling the variable.
 In your case, as `Load_newform` is another function (scope), `user` acessibility isn't set to it.
With that in mind, you have some ways to make it possible:

---

#### Pass the variable as parameter to the second method

```js
$('.comment').on('click', function(){ 
    var user = $(this).data("user"); 
    var number_comments = $(this).data("number_comments"); 
    if(number_comments){
        $(".LastComments").load(Load_newform(user));
    }else{
        Load_newform(user);
    }
});

function Load_newform(user) {
    form = "<form>Hi "+user+" post a comment</form>";
    $(".LastComments").append(form);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment" data-number_comments="7" data-user="Joe">
    [Click to comment]
</div>

<div class="LastComments"></div>
```

#### Create the variables in global scope

Please, remember that global variables can overwrite window variables!

```js
var user;

$('.comment').on('click', function(){ 
    user = $(this).data("user"); 
    var number_comments = $(this).data("number_comments"); 
    if(number_comments){
        $(".LastComments").load(Load_newform());
    }else{
        Load_newform();
    }
});

function Load_newform() {
    form = "<form>Hi "+user+" post a comment</form>";
    $(".LastComments").append(form);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment" data-number_comments="7" data-user="Joe">
    [Click to comment]
</div>

<div class="LastComments"></div>
```

*(You can automatically create one global variable without calling the `var` before the variable name)*

```js
$('.comment').on('click', function(){ 
    user = $(this).data("user"); 
    var number_comments = $(this).data("number_comments"); 
    if(number_comments){
        $(".LastComments").load(Load_newform());
    }else{
        Load_newform();
    }
});

function Load_newform() {
    form = "<form>Hi "+user+" post a comment</form>";
    $(".LastComments").append(form);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment" data-number_comments="7" data-user="Joe">
    [Click to comment]
</div>

<div class="LastComments"></div>
```

*(Or even using `window.variable name`)*

```js
$('.comment').on('click', function(){ 
    window.user = $(this).data("user"); 
    var number_comments = $(this).data("number_comments"); 
    if(number_comments){
        $(".LastComments").load(Load_newform());
    }else{
        Load_newform();
    }
});

function Load_newform() {
    form = "<form>Hi "+user+" post a comment</form>";
    $(".LastComments").append(form);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment" data-number_comments="7" data-user="Joe">
    [Click to comment]
</div>

<div class="LastComments"></div>
```

#### Create the function inside the event

It's not the best approach, because if you will always create the function when you click.

```js
$('.comment').on('click', function(){ 
    function Load_newform() {
        console.log(user);
        form = "<form>Hi "+user+" post a comment</form>";
        $(".LastComments").append(form);
    }
    var user = $(this).data("user"); 
    var number_comments = $(this).data("number_comments"); 
    if(number_comments){
        $(".LastComments").load(Load_newform());
    }else{
        Load_newform();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment" data-number_comments="7" data-user="Joe">
    [Click to comment]
</div>

<div class="LastComments"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

1) Get User Variable value by adding one line [i.e. var user = $(this).data("user");]

```
function Load_newform() {
  var user = $(this).data("user"); //Initialize user variable here.
  var form = "<form>Hi " + user + " post a comment </form>";
  $(".LastComments").append(form);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$(this).` ok I understood